# Using core OpenGL in SDL 1.2?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

Is there any way to create a core OpenGL context in SDL 1.2? I've been looking around, but Google only gives half completed tutorials that only work for Windows, when I need it to work on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "OpenGL 3.0".

If you're just talking about the version number, then SDL should still be capable. If you're talking about getting a [core context instead of a compatibility one](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts), then you'll either have to use a version of SDL that supports that (the in-development 2.0) or [something that isn't SDL](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Related_toolkits_and_APIs#OpenGL_initialization).

Comment: I meant the core context, yes. So there is no way to get a 3.0 or later core context in SDL 1.2?